# Simplify matching elements in SCSS

Tags: sass

The HTML DOM structure I have is, sort of, repetitive. Is there any good practice to refactor my sass rules?

#### HTML:

```
<div name="OpportunityDetailView" class="actor-wrapper"><div name="OpportunityDetailView" class="detail-view expansion-bottom-normal">...</div></div>

<div name="ApplicationDetailView" class="actor-wrapper"><div name="ApplicationDetailView" class="detail-view expansion-bottom-normal">...</div></div>

<div name="ProfileDetailView" class="actor-wrapper"><div name="ProfileDetailView" class="detail-view expansion-bottom-normal">...</div></div>
```

#### SCSS case 1:

```
div[name="OpportunityDetailView"] > div[name="OpportunityDetailView"],
div[name="ApplicationDetailView"] > div[name="ApplicationDetailView"],
div[name="ProfileDetailView"] > div[name="ProfileDetailView"],
{
 css rules...
}
```

#### SCSS case 2:

```
.section {
  div[name="Business_Image_Url__c"],
  div[name="Name"],
  div[name="Account_Name__c"],
  div[name="Business_Type__c"],
  div[name="Region_Province__c"] {
    .label{
      display: none !important;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I don't think you can do anything better for the first case, if those three selectors share the same rules. On the second case, you could put the `div` as an intermediate level between the `.section` and the individual attribute selectors and use the `&` to prepend them, but I really don't think it will make a difference in your case. It's pretty simple at the moment. There are many practices in general, so you can pick one depending on personal taste. At work, we use [this form of BEM](https://csswizardry.com/2013/01/mindbemding-getting-your-head-round-bem-syntax/), but it is only for names.

Comment: thanks for your useful advice.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not missing something, it seems like you can use the classes assigned to the elements to achieve what you want:

For case 1:

```
.actor-wrapper {
  .detail-view {
    //css code goes here
  }
}
```

and please provide some markup for the case 2.

If all the `div[name]` elements share the same class, then you can group them by that class, as done with the above example.

Comment: I think he must be using the `[name]` attribute selector because he has those as `contenteditable` and he wants to add style rules based on the type of "field".